# Custom Block Unable to Be Found

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have an Ubuntu LTS20.04 vm with with GNU Radio installed via PPA.  Following the [Guided Tutorial GNU Radio in C++](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_GNU_Radio_in_C%2B%2B), I've created, built, and installed a project identical to the sample presented within.

I went to set up the objective flow graph presented at the beginning of the tutorial in GNURadio companion, but when I attempt to execute the it, I get the following error:

```
Warning: failed to XInitThreads()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/GNURadio Flowgraphs/testqpsk.py", line 38, in <module>
    import tutorial
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tutorial'
```

What steps do I need to take to resolve this?  I should note that the PPA install does not seem to configure paths correctly, as I had to `EXPORT GR_PREFIX=/usr` to get `gr_modtool` to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that cmake's default install prefix (`/usr/local`) does not correspond with default Python search paths.  My resolution was the following:

`export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH`

Both this export statement and the `GR_PREFIX` export were added to my `~/.profile`.